# BS4 python script crashes immediately when running, but looking at the code it should be fine

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code. It's probably not the prettiest, but I tried. When I run it it creates the links.txt file, but the actual script crashes immediately without showing any error on the cmd. I tried researching BS4 and I really think this should work.

This was the initial script that I was trying to get working so I could eventually change it to only scrape the links within the 'card' class, but the fact that it cannot even scrape all the links I want to understand what I did wrong.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

sys.stdout = open("links.txt", "a")

for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        URL = f'https://wesbite.com/downloads/{x}/'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(5)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        links_with_text = []
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
            if a.text: 
                links_with_text.append(a['href'])
                print(links_with_text)
    except:
        continue
```

Example of the Card class I was evenmtually trying to scrape:

```
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="center">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://website.com/username/">username</a>
```

I took your suggestions removed the except, and realized that my indents were inconsistent. After fixing that and changing the page.text it seems to work. The code below:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

sys.stdout = open("links.txt", "a")

for x in range(0, 10):
    try:
        URL = f'https://wesbite.com/downloads/{x}/'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(5)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

        links_with_text = []
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            if a.text: 
                links_with_text.append(a['href'])
                print(links_with_text)
    except Exception as e:
        print('something went wrong')
```

Comment: Where do you set `html`? Should that be `page`?

Comment: Well it's not showing any error because you wrap the whole thing in a try/except block and don't do anything with the exception. You should at least do "except Exception as e" and then print e's stack trace.

Comment: the biggest mistake is `except` with out printing information about problem.

Comment: you need `page.text` instead of `html` in `BeautifulSoup(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `html` variable in `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` is not defined in the code you've posted, my guess is that's raising an exception, which is suppressed by your `catch` block. Remove the `try...catch` code and run it, exceptions are helpful information and suppressing them in this way will prevent you from finding the problem.